# Elastic Beanstalk cron import issue

Tags: cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I used Elastic Beanstalk to check that the code that saves the time as .txt every hour with the cron job works.

After that, I wrote the code that saves the time as saving the crawl result, but it did not work.

After a bit of debugging, it seems like an error that occurs because the module, such as from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, is not installed.

What should I do?

I am using the AL2 platform and below are test.py and cron-linux.config.

test.py

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def function_test():
    now = time.strftime('%H%M%S')
    now_int = int(now) + 90000 # UTC TO KST 시차가 +9시간 발생
    now_kst = now_int % 240000 # 시간은 24시 넘어가면 안되므로 24시간으로 나누어 줌
    now_str = str(now_kst).zfill(6)    
        
    if 90000 < now_kst and now_kst < 160000:
        print("intime")
    else:
        print("outtime")


    f=open('Enterprise.txt','w',encoding='UTF-8')
    f.write(now_str)
    f.close()

function_test()
```

cron-linux.config

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            */1 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh

    "/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash

            python3 /var/app/current/test.py

            exit 0

commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/mycron.bak"
```

The current .zip configuration is

```
-.ebextensions
     >cron-linx.config
-static
-templates
-application.py
-Enterprise.txt
-requirements.txt
-test.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install `bs4` using [container commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands):

> You can use the container_commands key to execute commands that affect your application source code. Container commands run after the application and web server have been set up and the application version archive has been extracted, but before the application version is deployed.

Thus you can create new `config` in your `.ebextensions`.

For example:

**.ebextensions/10_commands.config**

```
container_commands:
  10_install_bs4:      
    command: pip install bs4
  20_install_something_else:      
    command: pip install <other package>
```

**requirements.txt** - easier alternative

The easiest way would be to simply put all your pip requirements in the root folder of your app in `requirements.txt` file:

- [Specifying dependencies using a requirements file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/python-configuration-requirements.html)

Comment: I have some more questions. 
If you want to install other modules as well, 
command: pip install bs4
command: pip install somemodule


Can I add the above command?


Also can I use command: pip install bs4==0.0.1?


And is there a way to install modules at once like the requirements.txt file?

Comment: @김준우 Hi. Yes, `requirements.txt` would be probably easier. Just place it in the root folder of your application. I will update the answer. Somehow forgot about it :-)

Comment: I have already created and used the requirements.txt file.

Comment: @김준우 And I does not work? The container_commands work with cron, I run it on my EB environment.

Comment: How can I install additional modules from 10_commands.config?

Comment: @김준우 you can add new sections as in the updated answer.